# Cordova 5.3.1 Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I´ve got this code on my cordova app, with InAppBrowser plugin to open external web

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    if(PushbotsPlugin.isAndroid()){
        PushbotsPlugin.initializeAndroid("XXXX", "YYYYY");
        PushbotsPlugin.getToken(function(token){
          var url="http://subdomain.domain.com/deviceid/" + token + '/platform/1';
          document.getElementById("ge").addEventListener("click", irekiAndroid(url), false);
          var ref = window.open(url, '_blank','location=no');
        });
    }
    if(PushbotsPlugin.isiOS()){
        PushbotsPlugin.initializeiOS("XXXXX");
        PushbotsPlugin.getToken(function(token){
           var url="http://subdomain.domain.com/deviceid/"+ token + '/platform/0';

          document.getElementById("ge").addEventListener("click", irekiIOS(url), false);
          window.open(url, '_self','location=yes');
        });
    }

},
```

In android it works great but in iOS I´m getting this error:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

I checked all the other stackoverflow questions, but no one seems to be correct...

Any help or clue?

Comment: use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-transport-security. You shouldn't use _self param

Comment: thx @jcesarmobile but I tried and I´m getting the same error

Comment: @KiokoKiaza pls how do you resolved this issue? I am getting thesame error .